# How to Draw a Rose in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, draw, sketch

Is it possible to make a reasonably simple Latex facsimile of the following rose image:

[image]

The picture comes from a previously posted question on this site:

[How to set opacity of background picture and make two lines long text in right/left side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502107/how-to-set-opacity-of-background-picture-and-make-two-lines-long-text-in-right-l)

Ultimately, I would like to replace a box produce in Latex (such as the following) with a ``Latex rose''---containing a word or two---in order to introduce new chapters in a book.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What about `\includegraphics{rose}`? Why redraw it in TeX?

Comment: @gernot An actual photo image of a rose does not have the simplicity (and aesthetic appeal, I believe) of a simple uncomplicated sketch, which, I think, better serves the introduction of the chapters of the book I hope to produce.

Comment: I think this is more like a graphic designer's job. However, there are many online tools for you to stylize your image.

Comment: Put in a bitmap tracer (Inkscape has one built in, there's another one [here](https://www.visioncortex.org/vtracer/)) then tweak the number of colours and detail, and get the simpler sketch on the other side

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(100,100)
\thicklines
\put(100,20){\line(0,1){50}}
\thinlines
\put(103,93){\circle{10}}\put(102,92){\circle{20}}
\put(101,91){\circle{30}}\put(100,90){\circle{35}}
\put(115,30){\oval(30,10){}}\put(85,35){\oval(30,10){}}
\put(115,40){\oval(30,10){}}\put(85,45){\oval(30,10){}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Beautiful.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One rose...drawing with Mathcha....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt      
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,439); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 439

%Shape: Triangle [id:dp8966526263440768] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (334.24,270.96) -- (306.37,286.02) -- (302.75,274.36) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp2836988033968444] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (325.1,204.69) .. controls (309.16,208) and (298.01,219.19) .. (300.19,229.69) .. controls (302.37,240.19) and (317.05,246.02) .. (332.99,242.72) .. controls (348.92,239.41) and (360.07,228.22) .. (357.89,217.72) .. controls (355.26,205.04) and (354.61,198.05) .. (355.92,196.73) .. controls (354.61,198.05) and (344.33,200.7) .. (325.1,204.69) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp288253063079859] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (259.5,218.3) .. controls (279.79,214.09) and (298.01,219.19) .. (300.19,229.69) .. controls (302.37,240.19) and (287.68,252.12) .. (267.39,256.33) .. controls (247.09,260.54) and (228.87,255.44) .. (226.69,244.94) .. controls (224.06,232.26) and (221.68,225.63) .. (219.53,225.02) .. controls (221.68,225.63) and (235,223.38) .. (259.5,218.3) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp5120212632053505] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (306.49,77.85) .. controls (326.98,80.92) and (342.54,96.06) .. (342.54,114.28) .. controls (342.54,134.71) and (322.96,151.28) .. (298.79,151.28) .. controls (274.63,151.28) and (255.04,134.71) .. (255.04,114.28) .. controls (255.04,99.56) and (265.2,86.85) .. (279.91,80.89) -- (298.79,114.28) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp5535788958689252] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (287.37,102.56) .. controls (287.37,102.56) and (287.37,102.56) .. (287.37,102.56) .. controls (287.37,102.56) and (287.37,102.56) .. (287.37,102.56) .. controls (299.37,113.98) and (299.85,132.97) .. (288.43,144.98) .. controls (277.01,156.98) and (258.03,157.46) .. (246.02,146.04) .. controls (234.01,134.62) and (233.53,115.64) .. (244.95,103.63) .. controls (258.73,89.14) and (265.56,79.56) .. (265.45,74.89) .. controls (265.56,79.56) and (272.87,88.78) .. (287.37,102.56) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Moon [id:dp5000564586031293] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (287.37,102.56) .. controls (295.53,135.03) and (315.35,157.97) .. (331.63,153.79) .. controls (347.91,149.61) and (354.48,119.9) .. (346.31,87.43) .. controls (342.37,101.85) and (333.81,112.54) .. (322.01,115.57) .. controls (310.22,118.6) and (297.65,113.33) .. (287.37,102.56) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Moon [id:dp5949145834269645] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (296.7,125.74) .. controls (280.82,152.23) and (256.64,166.93) .. (242.68,158.57) .. controls (228.73,150.21) and (230.29,121.95) .. (246.16,95.46) .. controls (246.1,109.39) and (251.26,121.32) .. (261.37,127.38) .. controls (271.48,133.44) and (284.44,132.36) .. (296.7,125.74) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Moon [id:dp6478429282324447] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (333.88,94.51) .. controls (333.74,116.6) and (317.95,134.4) .. (298.62,134.28) .. controls (279.3,134.15) and (263.74,116.15) .. (263.88,94.05) .. controls (272.28,102.68) and (284.79,108.19) .. (298.79,108.28) .. controls (312.8,108.37) and (325.38,103.02) .. (333.88,94.51) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp9055944285562285] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (354.4,132.41) .. controls (354.4,132.41) and (354.4,132.41) .. (354.4,132.41) .. controls (354.4,132.41) and (354.4,132.41) .. (354.4,132.41) .. controls (366.03,143.49) and (357.22,163.97) .. (334.73,178.17) .. controls (312.24,192.36) and (284.57,194.9) .. (272.95,183.83) .. controls (261.32,172.75) and (270.12,152.27) .. (292.62,138.07) .. controls (319.77,120.94) and (334.49,109.69) .. (336.79,104.34) .. controls (334.49,109.69) and (340.36,119.05) .. (354.4,132.41) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp029259060568209927] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (296.7,125.74) .. controls (296.7,125.74) and (296.7,125.74) .. (296.7,125.74) .. controls (315.68,139.24) and (321.5,163.64) .. (309.7,180.24) .. controls (297.89,196.83) and (272.93,199.33) .. (253.95,185.83) .. controls (234.96,172.32) and (229.14,147.92) .. (240.95,131.32) .. controls (255.19,111.3) and (261.56,98.1) .. (260.04,91.72) .. controls (261.56,98.1) and (273.79,109.43) .. (296.7,125.74) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6066444677487759] 
\draw    (238,236) -- (280.5,234) ;
%Shape: Trapezoid [id:dp656123975124739] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (291,389) -- (297.45,190) -- (306.05,190) -- (312.5,389) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da36096148600738487] 
\draw    (250,252) -- (277.5,243) ;
%Shape: Moon [id:dp9381043746948583] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (355.98,146.55) .. controls (360.45,168.19) and (338.86,190.94) .. (307.77,197.37) .. controls (276.67,203.79) and (247.83,191.47) .. (243.36,169.83) .. controls (251.66,187.54) and (278.11,196.86) .. (306.45,191) .. controls (334.79,185.14) and (355.38,166.1) .. (355.98,146.55) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da43346633822675784] 
\draw    (315,223) -- (352.5,210) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da06894090327915348] 
\draw    (318,229) -- (345.5,233) ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp9158823263976328] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (271.11,319.79) -- (302.79,319.35) -- (300.6,331.36) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum with another rose**.....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (315.73,214.88) -- (322.94,393.73) -- (303.61,394.11) -- (303.64,215.12) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Moon [id:dp6198007041185263] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 131; green, 179; blue, 82 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 160; green, 214; blue, 100 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (364.07,146.11) .. controls (374.93,181.86) and (354.97,219.58) .. (319.5,230.35) .. controls (284.02,241.12) and (246.47,220.87) .. (235.61,185.11) .. controls (256.29,183.37) and (278.78,179.08) .. (301.81,172.08) .. controls (324.83,165.09) and (345.92,156.16) .. (364.07,146.11) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp24653128302961091] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 190; green, 19; blue, 40 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (241.88,150.76) .. controls (241.88,150.76) and (241.88,150.76) .. (241.88,150.76) .. controls (236.73,169.55) and (246.75,188.68) .. (264.25,193.48) .. controls (281.76,198.28) and (300.13,186.93) .. (305.28,168.14) .. controls (310.43,149.35) and (300.42,130.22) .. (282.91,125.42) .. controls (261.77,119.63) and (250.58,115.54) .. (249.33,113.14) .. controls (250.58,115.54) and (248.1,128.08) .. (241.88,150.76) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp48418373498632095] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 190; green, 19; blue, 40 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (260.26,144.1) .. controls (260.26,144.1) and (260.26,144.1) .. (260.26,144.1) .. controls (260.26,144.1) and (260.26,144.1) .. (260.26,144.1) .. controls (253.79,167.67) and (264.19,191.08) .. (283.49,196.36) .. controls (302.78,201.65) and (323.66,186.83) .. (330.12,163.25) .. controls (336.59,139.67) and (326.19,116.27) .. (306.89,110.98) .. controls (283.6,104.59) and (271.31,99.93) .. (270.01,97) .. controls (271.31,99.93) and (268.06,115.63) .. (260.26,144.1) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp9913812118283272] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 203; green, 53; blue, 71 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (291.38,126.95) .. controls (291.38,126.95) and (291.38,126.95) .. (291.38,126.95) .. controls (291.38,126.95) and (291.38,126.95) .. (291.38,126.95) .. controls (273.78,143.93) and (270.77,169.36) .. (284.66,183.76) .. controls (298.55,198.15) and (324.07,196.06) .. (341.67,179.09) .. controls (359.27,162.11) and (362.27,136.68) .. (348.38,122.29) .. controls (331.95,105.25) and (323.52,96.95) .. (323.1,97.36) .. controls (322.77,97.01) and (312.19,106.88) .. (291.38,126.95) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp8743320111586002] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 200; green, 24; blue, 46 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (274.48,162.44) .. controls (274.48,162.44) and (274.48,162.44) .. (274.48,162.44) .. controls (295.72,168.34) and (309.34,186.06) .. (304.91,202.02) .. controls (300.48,217.99) and (279.67,226.15) .. (258.44,220.26) .. controls (237.2,214.37) and (223.58,196.65) .. (228.01,180.68) .. controls (233.36,161.41) and (235.17,150.65) .. (233.44,148.41) .. controls (235.17,150.65) and (248.85,155.33) .. (274.48,162.44) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp06529253074145047] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 197; blue, 78 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (331.37,267.93) -- (311.86,278.17) -- (309.44,265.79) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp5613117809992467] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 169; green, 220; blue, 112 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (315.69,289.27) .. controls (307.3,301.11) and (292.04,312.03) .. (274.41,317.57) .. controls (247.23,326.1) and (224.73,318.61) .. (224.15,300.83) .. controls (224.13,300.31) and (224.13,299.79) .. (224.15,299.26) -- (273.35,285.38) -- cycle ; \draw  [draw opacity=0] (315.69,289.27) .. controls (307.3,301.11) and (292.04,312.03) .. (274.41,317.57) .. controls (247.23,326.1) and (224.73,318.61) .. (224.15,300.83) .. controls (224.13,300.31) and (224.13,299.79) .. (224.15,299.26) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp4888472946932019] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 169; green, 220; blue, 112 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (314.41,290.84) .. controls (315.41,289.13) and (315.92,287.51) .. (315.87,286.01) .. controls (315.58,276.99) and (295.19,276.02) .. (270.33,283.82) .. controls (249.43,290.38) and (232.02,301.07) .. (227.19,309.66) -- (270.87,300.14) -- cycle ; \draw  [draw opacity=0] (314.41,290.84) .. controls (315.41,289.13) and (315.92,287.51) .. (315.87,286.01) .. controls (315.58,276.99) and (295.19,276.02) .. (270.33,283.82) .. controls (249.43,290.38) and (232.02,301.07) .. (227.19,309.66) ;

%Shape: Arc [id:dp7863746929597304] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 174; green, 219; blue, 127 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (313.62,316.73) .. controls (318.54,327.9) and (330.26,333.25) .. (343.65,329.04) .. controls (360.98,323.6) and (374.53,304.22) .. (373.93,285.75) .. controls (373.92,285.41) and (373.9,285.09) .. (373.88,284.76) -- (342.55,295.6) -- cycle ; \draw  [draw opacity=0] (313.62,316.73) .. controls (318.54,327.9) and (330.26,333.25) .. (343.65,329.04) .. controls (360.98,323.6) and (374.53,304.22) .. (373.93,285.75) .. controls (373.92,285.41) and (373.9,285.09) .. (373.88,284.76) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp9935527042623047] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 174; green, 219; blue, 127 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (316.68,321.1) .. controls (316.39,320.26) and (316.22,319.36) .. (316.19,318.39) .. controls (315.89,309.03) and (328.49,297.4) .. (344.34,292.43) .. controls (358.63,287.94) and (370.69,290.39) .. (373.14,297.79) -- (344.89,309.38) -- cycle ; \draw  [draw opacity=0] (316.68,321.1) .. controls (316.39,320.26) and (316.22,319.36) .. (316.19,318.39) .. controls (315.89,309.03) and (328.49,297.4) .. (344.34,292.43) .. controls (358.63,287.94) and (370.69,290.39) .. (373.14,297.79) ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp9844400683196859] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 197; blue, 78 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (331.33,370.88) -- (309.3,370.22) -- (313.27,358.25) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp02649939092463871] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 197; blue, 78 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (289.83,255.76) -- (311.74,253.39) -- (309.44,265.79) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp6604794158903664] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 141; green, 197; blue, 78 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (291.71,341.53) -- (315.6,342.38) -- (309.29,353.3) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Tear Drop [id:dp8789476339204596] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 210; green, 44; blue, 64 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (318.33,146.65) .. controls (318.33,146.65) and (318.33,146.65) .. (318.33,146.65) .. controls (318.33,146.65) and (318.33,146.65) .. (318.33,146.65) .. controls (292.79,155.12) and (277.19,177.38) .. (283.49,196.36) .. controls (289.78,215.35) and (315.6,223.88) .. (341.14,215.4) .. controls (366.68,206.93) and (382.28,184.67) .. (375.98,165.68) .. controls (368.38,142.77) and (365.56,129.91) .. (367.52,127.12) .. controls (365.56,129.91) and (349.16,136.42) .. (318.33,146.65) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Resistor [id:dp855989959293115] 
\draw   (241.95,309.79) -- (252.75,306.76) -- (249.61,305.96) -- (265.49,304.87) -- (259.21,303.27) -- (275.08,302.17) -- (268.8,300.57) -- (284.68,299.48) -- (278.4,297.87) -- (294.27,296.78) -- (291.13,295.98) -- (301.93,292.95) ;
%Shape: Resistor [id:dp4675455647263771] 
\draw   (333.72,322.89) -- (338.84,318.03) -- (346.42,313.7) -- (335.8,318.03) -- (350.96,309.38) -- (340.35,313.71) -- (355.51,305.06) -- (344.89,309.38) -- (360.06,300.74) -- (349.44,305.06) -- (357.02,300.74) -- (362.14,295.88) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 You are an artist. Like ducks and people, we should also have a package for flowers ...

Comment: Yeah, procedural roses with `tikz`, L-systems for leafs and thorns, etc.

Comment: @gernot You don't think our many trees sufficient unto the `forest`s beauty?

Comment: Who the **** would downvote a rose?!

Comment: Wow......no words.....lovely.....

Comment: @cfr maybe the downvoter confused it with a tulip with thorns ;).

Comment: @gernot Thank you very very much for your comment...and excuse me very much for my delay comment due to various reasons (health). I give only the bounty and after yesterday or sunday I have closed! I am not an artist...:-) When I was little and I still like to draw today: I only made a small experiment with Mathcha...and I added a slightly different rose.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Hello very kind. Although Mathcha might seem simple is not so. To draw with Mathcha you have to invent something that can be adapted to the drawing. Mine is just a drawing of an elementary school student but it can never be a real rose. All the best.....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thank you and I am very pleased with your words because I love humble and simple people. Thank you with all my heart.

Comment: @Bubaya Surely it will be a rose-tulipan :-) ahahah. I always wish you the best from life.

Comment: @Sebastiano Very nice. Which lines of the code of the addendum rose pertain to the thorns---so that one may remove them if they were not wanted?

Comment: @Sebastiano It is too late for me to edit my previous comment---I found the code pertaining to the thorns. Thank you for your addendum rose.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Latex rose, especially the second one.

Comment: @J.BogdanYaromir I have seen your question on TeX.meta....:-) To create a rose it is necessary a bit of fantasy and patience. The link is this: https://www.mathcha.io/editor and if you want any explanation on this editor I am available hoping that you are not as tired as you are these days. I always wish you the best days.

Comment: @mlchristians Hi, thank you for your beautiful words. I ask you so kindly and I hope you will accept my invitation. You can give Gernot the green tick. His answer is better than mine. Thank you very much and I always wish you the best days in the future.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your kind and humble comment; if it's OK with you, I would like to keep things as they are---for although Germot provided a very, very nice rose indeed---I had asked for a Latex rose---which you so kindly provided, and a very nice one as well---I am, however, grateful to both you and Germot for very excellent answers! Thank you again, and the very best to you as well!

Comment: @mlchristians Hi, and I will accept your desire. I always wish you the best.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you very much for responding to my Meta question. And thank you for the provided link.

Comment: @J.BogdanYaromir Happy to help you and always wish you every possible happiness.

Comment: @Sebastiano If you don't mind, can I get your email id? Please...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Yes with a lot of pleasure. When you are here, please, post your message. I write quickly my email and after when you have copied it, I will delete it. My bestttttt regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano Best wishes and thanks....

Comment: I thought that is is a joke drawing a rose! great answer!

Comment: @Mikasa ahhahahahah . Thus my face I become my face with the red colour :-)))))

Answer (score 48):

You can load the image into `inkscape`, choose `Path | Trace Bitmap` to obtain an svg file (using only 8 colors), and then use [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) to convert the svg file to a tex file using tikz. The result is the image below.

[image]

The tex source is too big to post here; it looks like this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{cfcfbfb}{RGB}{252,251,251}
\definecolor{c878c58}{RGB}{135,140,88}
\definecolor{c7b824e}{RGB}{123,130,78}
\definecolor{c6b744b}{RGB}{107,116,75}
\definecolor{ccc2429}{RGB}{204,36,41}
\definecolor{c555e30}{RGB}{85,94,48}
\definecolor{ca3161c}{RGB}{163,22,28}
\definecolor{c63050b}{RGB}{99,5,11}

\def \globalscale {1.000000}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-\globalscale, xscale=\globalscale, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]

  \begin{scope}[shift={(-185.20833,28.72619)}]
    \path[fill=cfcfbfb,line width=0.212pt] (235.3658,101.2083) -- (235.3658,25.9344) -- (293.3095,25.9344) -- (351.2533,25.9344) -- (351.2533,101.2083) -- (351.2533,176.4823) -- (293.3095,176.4823) -- (235.3658,176.4823) -- cycle;

  % 7 more path statements, some up to 40000 characters long.

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @gernot Thank you. Another question if I may---Is it possible, if one wanted to, to also change the petal color from red to white with the process you described?

Comment: @mlchristians The tikz code starts with defining the eight colors used in the drawing, so you can change them any way you  like.

Comment: Perhaps all the draw-this-complicated-thing-for-me's should link to this answer?