# Wikipedia Lipschitz continuity in Tikz or Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Anyone knows how to elegantly improve the following wikipedia (wikimedia) image quality from a Lipschitz continuity function to make it vectorial in Tikz or Pgfplots?

[Wikimedia Lipschitz continuit](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Lipschitz_continuity.png)

Visible here below:

[image]

Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Maybe [this answer to the post "How to Draw a Rose in Latex"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570492/110998) helps. It describes how to obtain tikz code from a given image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's pretty challenging to imitate the function shown in your image exactly, I've created something else that may help you to accomplish the same goal—here's a little script that creates an arbitrary Lipschitz-continuous function from a random number generator.

You can customize what the output looks like by tinkering around with these three parameters:

- `\numSamples` - the number of random samples used to create the function. More samples result in a more jagged-looking function.
- `\K` - the Lipschitz constant of the function
- `\pgfmathsetseed` - sets the seed of Ti*k*z's random number generator

### Example output

[image: These are two generated graphs of Lipschitz-continuous functions, with green lines to indicate that the absolute value of the function's derivative is always bounded by the slopes of the lines. The function on the left was generated with 50 samples, K = 1, and a seed of 123456789. The function on the right was generated with 143 samples, K = 2.718, and a seed of 1729]

---

### Code

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\def\numSamples{50} 
\def\K{1}
\pgfmathsetseed{123456789}

\def\lipschitzFunc{(0,0)}

\tikzmath{
  \funcValue = 0; % the graph begins at the origin
  for \n in {1,...,\numSamples} { 
    if \n <= \numSamples / 2 then { % first, generate the right side of the graph
      \deltaX = 4 / int(\numSamples / 2);
      \funcValue = \funcValue + rand * \K * \deltaX;
      \xVal = \n * \deltaX;
      {\global\edef\lipschitzFunc{\lipschitzFunc(\xVal,\funcValue)}};
    }
    else { % then, come back and generate the left side of the graph
      if \n == 1 + int(\numSamples / 2) then {
        \funcValue = 0;
      };
      \deltaX = 4 / int((\numSamples + 1)/ 2);
      \funcValue = \funcValue + rand * \K * \deltaX;
      \xVal = (int(\numSamples / 2) - \n) * \deltaX;
      {\global\edef\lipschitzFunc{(\xVal,\funcValue)\lipschitzFunc}};
    };
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin  = -4,
  xmax  =  4,
  ymin  = -4,
  ymax  =  4,
  xtick = \empty,
  ytick = \empty,
  axis on top,
  %axis line style={draw=none} % uncomment this line to remove surrounding box
]
\addplot[smooth] coordinates {\lipschitzFunc};
\addplot[name path = downup, color = LimeGreen, very thick]{ \K * x};
\addplot[name path = updown, color = LimeGreen, very thick]{-\K * x};
\addplot[fill = PaleGreen]
  fill between
  [
    of = updown and downup,
    soft clip = {domain = 0:4}
  ];
\addplot[fill = PaleGreen]
  fill between
  [
    of = downup and updown,
    soft clip = {domain = -4:0}
  ];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that's perfect IMHO. Thanks a lot in the name of the community!

Comment: @VincentISOZ I'm glad you found this answer useful! And unlike the Wikimedia image, now you won't have to worry about the licensing for the image because it's automatically generated :)